# Using ORMLite for Android, does allow creation of Table with Certain Column Names

Tags: android, database, sqlite, ormlite

I was just About to create a Sample for Proper Understanding on how the Hello Android for ORMLite works in Android.

```
    public class SchoolDataBean {


// id is generated by the database and set on the object automagically
@DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
int rollNo;
@DatabaseField(index = true)
String name;
@DatabaseField
String gender;
@DatabaseField
boolean presence;

public SchoolDataBean() {
//required by ORM :)
}

public void setRollNo(int rollNo) {
    this.rollNo = rollNo;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

public void setPresence(boolean presence) {
    this.presence = presence;
}

}
```

In the Database Helper when I try Inserting the initial Values and creating the table with

```
      SchoolDataBean schoolDataSecond = new SchoolDataBean();
    schoolDataSecond.setName("Ram");
    schoolDataSecond.setGender("F");
    schoolDataSecond.setPresence(true);
    schoolDataSecond.setRollNo(2);
    dao.create(schoolDataSecond);
```

I get this exception from the ORMLite Library as

```
  sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = duplicate column name: gender

   java.sql.SQLException: SQL statement failed: CREATE TABLE `schooldata` (`rollNo` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , `name` VARCHAR , `gender` VARCHAR , `gender` VARCHAR , `presence` SMALLINT )
```

thanks everyone.

```
      The Exception seems to be caused at this line
        TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, SchoolDataBean.class);
```

Comment: ok Resolved it, as it required changes to be made in the ormlite_config.txt file in the raw folder as well according to the column/field name changes made.

Comment: Just to be sure, so you updated your database object but did not update your `config.txt` file?

Comment: Yes I realized that the Config.txt needs to be generated running it as a Java application by setting the JRE and removing the Boot Strap. missed on that part in the Documentation written by you

Comment: Out of curiosity why didn't you use the in class annotations? It makes it where you don't have to have a separate file.

Comment: didn't actually get you, can you throw some more light on it with an example or anything you have to make it more easy, would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i didn't realize that I needed to check the Config.txt for Column names too, there it was, two similar column names which caused this duplication problem.